# Can one upload files using AMP validated html?

Tags: amp-html

Can one upload files using AMP validated html?  It seems that the input type="file" is disabled in the amp-form html.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. Check [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form#inputs-and-fields) and [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/9791). No image support though, for the moment...

Answer (score 0):

No. We can't upload file till now with AMP validation. AMP HTML is HTML with some restrictions for reliable performance. In future AMP will give some options to upload file. But at present there is no solution for file upload page with AMP validated HTML.

**AMP Inputs and Fields:**

***Allowed:***

- Other form-related elements, including: `<textarea>`, `<select>`, `<option>`, `<fieldset>`, `<label>`, `<input type=text>`, `<input type=submit>`, and so on.
- `[amp-selector][1]`

***Not Allowed:***

- `<input type=button>`, `<input type=file>`, `<input type=image>` and `<input type=password>`
- Most of the `form-related` attributes on inputs including: `form`, `formaction`, `formtarget`, `formmethod` and others.